xcode could not find any of my flutter package path or file
I am running into an issue while trying to build for iOS, at first it was

no such file or directory: 'firebase_core'.

After removing firebase from my project and trying to build again, the same issue came up but with different flutter package this time

no such file or directory: 'flutter_inappwebview'.

I have searched everywhere and could not find any solution
I removed "firebase" package thinking it would fix the issue, Just for same issue to pop up for a different package flutter_inappwebview

Try command flutter clean after that run command flutter pub get. Also clean build.gradle from android folder with ./gradlew clean command.

I have tried all that, I could build it for android without no issue. @DroidFlutter
